# Angular custom search filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, dirpagination

I need to create a custom search filter for this scope. I tried the default filter function , doesn't works, Because I displayed status as string in HTML and it is not filtered the way I want it.  If I type Normal in the textbox, nothing happens because the data is 0, 1 and 2.  And if I search the purchase time which is in 2016/05/16 format cannot search also.

```
$scope.orderHistory = {[
    "purchaseTime": 1437536718345,
    "status": 1,
]};
app.filter('filterSearch', function () {
  //what to do here??
});


<input type="text" ng-model="searchReview">

<div dir-paginate="order in orderHistory|filterSearch:searchReview">
<ul>
 <li><p class="table-data2-h">{{ order.purchaseTime | date : 'yyyy/MM/dd'}} </p></li>
<li>
<span ng-if="order.status == 0 ">Stable</span>
<span ng-if="order.status == 1 ">Normal</span>
<span ng-if="order.status == 2 ">Serious</span>
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: You know you have some mistakes in that code above? There's nothing about `sportorderreply.orderStatus` in your `object`.. as in `<span ng-if="order.sportorderreply.orderStatus == 0 ">Stable</span>`.. it's only `status`.. also, your `construction` should be `$scope.orderHistory = [{` instead of `$scope.orderHistory = {[`.

Comment: My bad sir, didn;t notice that, but I edit the code and your answer below is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I saw some mistakes on your `code`, you can compare it below.

I'd suggest you to create a simple `function` to parse your properties accordingly your requirements only on **initilization** (which one for sure will be better to parse everytime when than *custom* `filter` is called), then you can use the *normal* `filter`.

See it *working*:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .constant('STATUS', {
      0: 'Stable',
      1: 'Normal',
      2: 'Serious'
    })
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'STATUS'];

  function MainCtrl($scope, STATUS) {
    $scope.orderHistory = [
      {
        "purchaseTime": 1437536718345,
        "status": 1
      },
      {
        "purchaseTime": 1431236718345,
        "status": 0
      },
      {
        "purchaseTime": 1099536718345,
        "status": 2
      },
      {
        "purchaseTime": 1439744718345,
        "status": 1
      }
    ];

    function parseProperties() {
      $scope.orderHistory.map(function(order) {
        // You can do it with switch statement
        // switch (order.status) {
        //   case 0:
        //     order.status = 'Stable';
        //     break;
        //   case 1:
        //     order.status = 'Normal';
        //     break;
        //   case 2:
        //     order.status = 'Serious';
        //     break;
        // }

        // or using a constant that you can define above
        order.status = STATUS[order.status];

        order.purchaseTime = new Date(order.purchaseTime).toLocaleDateString();
        return order;
      });
    }

    parseProperties();
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchReview">
  <div ng-repeat="order in orderHistory | filter: searchReview">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p class="table-data2-h" ng-bind="order.purchaseTime"></p>
      </li>
      <li ng-bind="order.status"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Hi Sir, it works fine , thank you very much. but can I ask one more question.  in my json array i have a data which is **'rate':'abnormal'** but i am not displaying that data. and when I search **Normal** the data with rate abnormal is displaying

Comment: You can simply add the `status` to the Constant.. e.g: `3: 'Abnormal'`

Comment: Hi Sir, Can you help me with this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950456/angular-date-filter-on-ng-click